# Random CSS loading issues

Tags: css, wordpress, text, menu, menubar

I am having some really random issues on two of my sites at the moment.

The two sites in question are http://djstephenjarmuz.co.uk/ and http://subduce.com/

I can only explain the issues as intermitent, and they seem to be CSS related. Like the sylesheet isn't loading.

**THE SYMPTOMS**
After a full refresh (no-Cache) CTLR+F5 job.

- Menu bars are not visible until elements are inspected (http://djstephenjarmuz.co.uk/)
  [image: After refreshing the page][image: After inspecting the element]
- Some text is not visible. Present but transparent on content pages (http://subduce.com/)
- Menu bars do not load the text on until hovered over, which seems to trigger the loading (http://subduce.com/)
  [image: before swiping the mouse across the screen][image: after swiping the mouse across the screen]

Hopefully some bright spark will be able to show me where this is coming from.

and then others will be able to solve there own similar issues.

Thanks

Comment: Please note, as far as I can see, it never happens on my iPad, just my Windows 7 Desktop and my MacBook Pro running OSX Mavericks